# Why is unbiased estimation from a sample only possible for certain properties?

Tags: sample, unbiased-estimator, entropy

I was thinking about finding some monotonic measure of entropy of a sample from a continuous distribution (2D, btw), but couldn't think of any such without making assumptions.

Why is it that one can make an unbiased estimation of certain properties of a distribution from a sample (like mean, variance, etc.), but not others (like entropy, maximum, mode)?

Relatedly, does this problem formally go away for sufficient sample size? For example:
Given N points, is there a certain bracket size B which could be chosen such that, as N approaches infinity, the entropy of a histogram approximation of the distribution (with bracket size B) would converge to that of the distribution?

EDIT:

[image: entropy definition]

Comment: How do you define entropy (as a mathematical expression)?

Comment: @Xi'an The definition for Information entropy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) - with a continuous form as Differential entropy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) - seems fine to me.

Comment: It is not a matter of being fine or not, but of self contained questions: please include the formula in your question.